# Data processing - BigQuery vs Data Proc+BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We have large volumes (10 to 400 billion) of raw data in `BigQuery` tables. We have a requirement to process this data to convert and create the data in the form of star schema tables (probably a different dataset in bigquery)  which can then be accessed by atscale.

**Need pros and cons between two options below:**
 
**1.** Write complex SQL within `BigQuery`  which reads data form source dataset and then loads to target dataset (used by Atscale).
**2.** Use `PySpark`  or `MapReduce`  with `BigQuery`  connectors from `Dataproc`  and then load the data to `BigQuery`  target dataset.

The complexity of our transformations involve joining multiple tables at different granularity, using analytics functions to get the required information, etc.
Presently this logic is implemented in vertica using multiple temp tables for faster processing and we want to re-write this processing logic in GCP (Big Query or Data Proc)

Comment: How frequently will this process be executed?

Comment: We are looking at executing them on a daily basis as part of ETL loads or even multiple times  a day.

Answer (score 2):

I went successfully with option 1: Big Query is very capable to run the very complex transformation with SQL, on top of that you can also run them incrementally with time range decorators. Note that it takes a lot of time and resources to take data back and forth to BigQuery. When running BigQuery SQL data never leaves BigQuery in the first place and you already have all raw logs there. So as long your problem can be solved by a series of SQL I believe this is the best way to go.

We moved out Vertica reporting cluster, rewriting successfully ETL last year, with option 1.

Around a year ago, I've written POC comparing DataFlow and series of BigQuery SQL jobs orchestrated by [potens.io](https://potens.io/) workflow allowing SQL parallelization at scale.

I took a good month to write DataFlow in Java with 200+ data points and complex transformation with terrible debugging capability at a time.
And a week to do the same using a series of SQL with [potens.io](https://potens.io/) utilizing
Cloud Function for [Windowed Tables](https://github.com/viant/bqwt) and parallelization with clustering transient tables.
I  know there's been bunch improvement in CloudDataFlow since then, but at a time
the DataFlow did fine only at a million scale and never-completed at billions record input (main reason shuffle cardinality went little under billions of records, with each records having 200+ columns). And the SQL approach produced all required aggregation under 2 hours for a dozen billion. Debugging and easiest of troubleshooting with potens.io helped a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

Both `BigQuery` and `DataProc` can handle huge amounts of complex data.

I think that you should consider two points:

1. Which transformation would you like to do in your data?

   Both tools can make complex transformations but you have to consider that `PySpark` will provide you a full programming language processing capability while `BigQuery` will provide you SQL transformations and some scripting structures. If only SQL and simple scripting structures can handle your problem, `BigQuery` is an option. If you need some complex scripts to transform your data or if you think you'll need to build some extra features involving transformations in the future, `PySpark` may be a better option. You can find the BigQuery scripting reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting)
2. Pricing

   `BigQuery` and `DataProc` have different pricing systems. While in `BigQuery` you'd need to concern about how much data you would process in your queries, in `DataProc` you have to concern about your cluster's size and VM's configuration, how much time your cluster would be running and some other configurations. You can find the pricing reference for `BigQuery` [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) and for `DataProc`  [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/pricing). Also, you can simulate the pricing in the [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)

I suggest that you create a simple POC for your project in both tools to see which one has the best cost benefit for you.

I hope these information help you.